# Estimates for tensors using local coordinates

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, tensor

Suppose that we have a Kähler manifold $(M, \omega_0)$ and another $(1,1)$ form $\eta$ on $M$. Let $\varphi$ be a smooth function such that $\omega_{\varphi} = \omega_0 + i \partial \bar \partial \varphi$ is positive.  Denote the metric tensor of $\omega_0$ by $g_{i \bar j}$ and $g_0^{i \bar j} = \delta_{i j}$, first derivative of $g_0$ vanishes and $\partial_{i} \bar \partial_{j} \varphi = \varphi_{i \bar j}= \varphi_{i \bar i}$ if $i = j$ and $0$ if $ i \neq j$.

My question is about how to properly estimate tensorial quantity in local coordinates:

For instance if we look at and $\sum_{i}\frac{R_{i  \bar i j \bar k} \varphi_{j} \varphi_{\bar k}}{1+\varphi_{i \bar i}}$, one can estimate:

$\sum_{i}\frac{R_{i  \bar i j \bar k} \varphi_{j} \varphi_{\bar k}}{1+\varphi_{i \bar i}} \geq -C |\partial \varphi|^2 \sum_{i} \frac{1}{1+\varphi_{i \bar i}}$

where $R_{i \bar i j \bar k} = -\partial_{j} \partial_{\bar k} g_{i \bar i} + g^{p \bar q}\partial_{j} g_{i \bar q} \partial_{\bar k} g_{p \bar i}$

1). How to make sense of this $C$ here? Is it coming from the bound on $|R_{i \bar i j \bar k}|$? I do not think it make sense to give bounds to individual component function of tensors which is not invariant under coordinate change.

2). In normal coordinates $R_{i \bar i j \bar k}$ only depends on mixed second derivative of the metric tensor, but in ordinary coordinates it also depends on the inverse of the metric tensor and the first derivative of the metric tensor. What is really the dependence on $\omega_0$?

I know that this might be too elementary for this site and I also posted it here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695760/estimates-for-tensors-using-local-coordinates
but no one seems to be interested in answering. I will delete this post if it can be answered on the post in the link.